# wooCommerce ajax submission to same checkout page does not work

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

Upon updating wooCommerce to latest version, the checkout page *`https://my_website.com/checkout/`* now does not submit to the same page *(i.e. `/checkout/` page)* instead it submits to the root url *`(https://my_website.com/?wc-ajax=checkout)`*.

Is there a possible workaround or solution when placing orders to restore the original behavior which is submitting orders to:
*`(https://my_website.com/checkout/?wc-ajax=checkout)`*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that the issue is caused by a recent change maid in latest wooCommerce version by using `home_page` for all ajax request in the shop.

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/commit/fbe6db5c02077a548eb1a386076d59261017145f#diff-133db5662c51f5686d87611121a05a3b

**Workaround**:

Restore previous implementation by changing line 35 in `includes/class-wc-ajax.php` file *( inside `get_endpoint` function)*:

```
return esc_url_raw( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint', add_query_arg( 'wc-ajax', $request, remove_query_arg( array( 'remove_item', 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart' ), home_url( wp_unslash( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ) ) ) ), $request ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter called `woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint` to achieve this, instead of editing the source code.

This worked for me:

```
function filter_woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint( $add_query_arg, $request ) { 
    return add_query_arg( 'wc-ajax', $request, remove_query_arg( array( 'remove_item', 'add-to-cart', 'added-to-cart', 'order_again', '_wpnonce' ), home_url( 'NEW URL', 'relative' ) ) );
}; 

add_filter( 'woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint', 'filter_woocommerce_ajax_get_endpoint', 10, 2 );
```